# Problemas de maven, plugin site y java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass

Tags: java, maven, dependencias

Cada vez que uso un comando de maven me da estas advertencias al inicio:

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Cuando uso el mvn site me muestra estas advertencias y el error de la clase java lang:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.0.0
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.CiManagementReport
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
```

Después de eso me dice que hay muchos errores no lo pongo porque es demaciado pero después me da esta causa:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent
```

Me muestra mas errores pero aquí ya no me dice causas y después me muestra que el site falló y me dice todo esto:

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.246 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-19T20:03:22+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project Colegio: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
```

Después de eso más errores otra vez. Son demasiados pero creo que estos son los clave. Mi **pom.xml** es muy sencillo solo tengo esto. Busqué la dependencia del doxia site render pero no paso nada. Quité el javadoc, daba el mismo error. Probé a eliminar la carpeta **.m2** para que la descargara otra ves y tampoco sirvió.

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las dos advertencias del inicio no están relacionadas con tu problema, son advertencias de que algunas librerías usan "trucos" que igual no estén permitidos en el futuro.

[Una búsqueda de "org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.documentcontent class not found"](https://www.google.com/search?q=org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.documentcontent+class+not+found) nos lleva a páginas como [esta](https://mkyong.com/maven/mvn-site-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-doxia-siterenderer-documentcontent/) o [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091539/maven-site-plugins-3-3-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-doxia) que nos avisan de un problema con el plugin "site" por defecto (version 3.3) y que mejor especificamos una versión más avanzada.

En concreto, en tu pom.xml

```
   ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```